# Using values emitted from Observable to call service method

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I get an array of profiles, and I need to display all the categories from each profile in the array.

```
export class ProfileCategoriesComponent implements OnInit {
  currentProfilesUser$: Observable<ProfileUser[]> = new Observable<ProfileUser[]>();
  currentProfileCategories$: Observable<ProfileCategory[]> = new Observable<ProfileCategory[]>();

  //(I get the userId from a parentComponent)
  @Input() userId!: string;

  constructor(private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // (I call my service, who return an Observable of type ProfileUser[])
    this.currentProfilesUser$ = this.profileService.getProfilesForUser(this.userId);
```

So, here I have an Observable typed ProfileUser[], ProfileUser contains a property profileId and I need the value of that property to get all profile categories.

Here I'm stuck, I need to get into the observable, get the profileId value and for each profile call my service "**this.profileService.getProfileCategories(this.profileId)**" and merge all the emitted value in an Observable of type ProfileCategory[].

I'm using | pipe async in HTMl side to iterate in Observables. Any idea ?
Thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
currentProfileCategories$ = this.currentProfilesUser$.pipe(
  concatMap(profilesUsers => {
    const categories$ = profilesUsers.map(pu => this.profileService.getProfileCategories(pu.profileId));
    return forkJoin(categories$).pipe(
      defaultIfEmpty([]) // just in case there are no profilesUsers
    );
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try tomorrow and give a feedback :)

Comment: It doens't seems to work, issues with types compatibility:

Type 'Observable<never[] | ProfileMaterialCategory[][]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<ProfileMaterialCategory>'.
  Type 'never[] | ProfileMaterialCategory[][]' is not assignable to type 'ProfileMaterialCategory'.
    Property 'quantity' is missing in type 'never[]' but required in type 'ProfileMaterialCategory'.ts(2322)

I succed by stopping using Observables. For the moment I will let it like this, I will come back to it later. Thx for your time :)

Comment: ok... 
Quick tip: you can alsways use `as any` if you have problems with types. It's not good practice but it's Ok if you just want to test and understand what's going wrong